# Sinch SDK seems very large @ 199kb

Tags: sinch, sinch-verification

is it possible to customize the [SDK](https://github.com/sinch/sinch-js-rtc/blob/master/sinch.min.js) size using npm if I'm only using 1 or 2 features? ie. verification and/or SMS

Answer (score 0):

No, thats not possible. Its only on SDK